# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'match' when I do reg exp

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to read a file and try the below regexp to find the existance of a particular string but then end up with the follow error.

```
if re.match("(.*)hello.%s_world"%(str(what_name)), lines):
```

Get the below error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'match'
```

What could be the basic error or issue ? Kindly clarify the same !

Update: 
When I copied the same file and tried as a small experiment it works fine. But when I try the same in my bigger script i get the above error !

Comment: somewhere you redefined `re` with a number.

Comment: Presumably you have a variable defined as name `re` and the value of which is an integer that shadowed the original `re` module.

Comment: OH crap.. Yes,, have some variable defined as re in the bigger script.. Will try to correct and give a try.. thanks a lot for the quick comments !